# Reconstructing a list of divisors from the prime factors (recursively)

Tags: c#, math, recursion, prime-factoring

I have a list of the prime factors of a number in the following form:
int[] factors = {number of factors,factor1,poweroffactor1,factor2,poweroffactor2,...};

I want to get the equivalent of dynamically nested for loops that will yield all the factors, where the for loops will look something like this:

```
int currentpod = 1;
for(int i=0;i<factors[2];i++)
{
    currentprod *= Math.Pow(factors[1],i);
    for(int j=0;j<factors[4];j++)
    {
         currentprod *= Math.Pow(factors[3],i);
         ...
         //When it hits the last level (i.e. the last prime in the list, it writes it to a list of divisors
         for(int k=0;k<factors[6];k++)
         {
              divisors.Add(Math.Pow(factors[5],k)*currentprod);
         }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code blows up as currentprod does not get reset enough.
Here is the actual code that I am using to try an accomplish this:

```
        public static List<int> createdivisorlist(int level, List<int> factors, int[] prodsofar,List<int> listsofar)
    {
        if (level == factors[0])
        {
            prodsofar[0] = 1;
        }
        if (level > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2*(factors[0]-level)+1; i++)
            {
                prodsofar[level-1] = prodsofar[level] * (int)Math.Pow(factors[2 * (factors[0] - level) + 1], i);
                listsofar =  createdivisorlist(level - 1, factors, prodsofar, listsofar);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= factors.Last(); i++)
            {
                listsofar.Add(prodsofar[level] * (int)Math.Pow(factors[2 * (factors[0] - level) + 1], i));
                if (listsofar.Last() < 0)
                {
                    int p = 0;
                }
            }
            return listsofar;
        }
        return listsofar;
    }
```

the original arguments are: 
level = factors[0]
factors = a list of the prime factors in the format specified above
prodsofar[] = all elements are 1
listsofar = an empty list

How can i reset prodsofar so that it does not "blow up" and instead just does what I outlined?
Note: as a test, use 2310, as under the current code, the divisor to be added is negative (int overflow).

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated. What are `prodsofar` and `listsofar` supposed to represent?

Comment: the current product (to be passed to the next instance of the function so that it can be multiplied) and listsofar is the list of divisors.

Comment: I know c++, but not c#. Even so I see what look like bugs. The loop limit doesn't look right, `prodsofar` can be an `int`, not an `int[]`, and you can use `*=` and do away with `Pow`. Have you tried running it on 2, before attempting 2310?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the recursive algorithm you have in mind is to keep an accumulating list of divisors. For that, the following code is an example of how to do it (retaining your notation: since "divisors" and "factors" mean exactly the same thing, the multiple terminology is unfortunate):

```
public static List<int> divisors(int[] factors, List<int> foundfactors, int level)
{
    if(level > factors[0]) return foundfactors;

    int current = 1;
    List<int> curpowers = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0; i<factors[2*level]+1; ++i)
    {
        curpowers.Add(current);
        current *= factors[2*level-1];
    }
    List<int> newfactors = new List<int>();
    foreach(int d in foundfactors)
        foreach(int n in curpowers)
            newfactors.Add(d*n);
    return divisors(factors, newfactors, level + 1);
}
```

Call it with something like

```
    // 600 = 2^3 * 3^1 * 5^2
    int[] pfactors = new int[] {3, 2,3, 3,1, 5,2};
    List<int> foundfactors = new List<int> {1};
    List<int> ds = divisors(pfactors, foundfactors, 1);
    foreach(int d in ds) Console.WriteLine(d);
```

which prints all 24 divisors of 600.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a "generate all combinations" problem. You can use your favorite search engine to find ways of doing this in C#; [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx) is one example.

Note that you'll need to need to map "prime p used k times" to `{p, p, p, ...`} (k times).

Comment: i mean i could do it that way, but really, i just want all the products, and it would seem that if i do it as a combinations problem i would incur extra overhead.

Comment: and would it be possible for you to write an example for how it would look using the library you sent me a link for?

Comment: in addition, it cannot handle combinations with repetition, which is a key part of what i need.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the accepted answer - it may be a little clearer to someone trying to understand whats going on...

```
def divisors_from_primes(primes, v = 1)
  if primes.empty?
    puts v
    return
  end
  p = primes.keys.first
  m = primes[p]
  primes.delete(p)
  0.upto(m) do |power|
    divisors_from_primes(primes, v * (p**power))
  end  
  primes[p] = m
end

/* 72 = 2**3 * 3**2  */

divisors_from_primes({ 2 => 3, 3 => 2})
```

So in this example (72), its basically a recursive version of:

```
0.upto(3) do |twopower|
  0.upto(2) |threepower|
    puts 2**twopower * 3**threepower
  end
end
```